# Intern 2.0 test stuck after running client.html page

Tags: selenium, dojo, selenium-webdriver, intern

I have a local selenium server (2.42.2) running with Chromedriver and Firefox. It seems to get stuck after loading and running client.html. I can see that my functional suite code runs in node, far enough to execute the main body. Anything in registerSuite never gets called.

Here are the selenium logs:

http://pastebin.com/KKg5ycvW

I can see the browsers in the selenium sessions page, but they don't appear to be doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up a new browser window and paste in the url that you see in the existing selenium ones. Then open up dev tools and see what console errors you are getting.

Intern's runner seems to get stuck in an infinite loop if any uncaught javascript errors are thrown during unit tests if the 'reporter' hasn't been setup yet.

This has been raised as an [issue](https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/254) in intern's github repository.